# Black vertical lines appearing when using css transition while changing zoom (chrome)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm using Angular4 and I wrote a simple a menu that opens horizontally. For unknown reason when "playing" a little with the menu on different zoom ratios, I noticed some black vertical lines that remains after closing the menu. if I change to another window or change the zoom ratio again, the lines disappear, but I don't understand why they are there from the first place.

**NOTE:**
The behavior is not consistent. Sometimes there are lines, sometimes not. If there are lines they appear on different places. On 100% scale there is no problems at all.

[image]

```
.menu-container {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  bottom: 23.81rem;
  left: 1.625rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-content-hide {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.menu-content-show {
  height: 0;
  width: 36.06rem;
}
```

html

```
 <div class="menu-container"
           [ngClass]="{'menu-content-show': selectedItem, 'menu-content-hide': !selectedItem}">
        <app-menu-content (_onClose)="handleMenuClicked(null)" [_selectedItem]="selectedItem"></app-menu-content>
      </div>
```